# How to use static C++ library in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm building an app on iOS based on Unity3d, and I need a static library(.a) linked in unity. 
But it seems you can't import .a libraries directly in Unity, and you have to import it in XCode projects. You have to wrote some extra code in XCode as middleware. Since communicate between C# & C++ will cause some performance issue (about 3-5 frames delay), is there the only way to use static C++ library in Unity?

Comment: Have you seen [Mixing Unity generated code with Objective-C in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com//questions/4272413/mixing-unity-generated-code-with-objective-c-in-ios)? You can copy .a and .h files into Assets/Plugins/iOS and they will be trasferred automatically. But if you need directory structures it won't work

Comment: Funny, I was curious about this question and my first Google search turned up @Kay 's site.

Comment: @Kay your solution is what I'm doing right now, but the difference is I add these .a files manually in XCode project generated by Unity. Unfortunately your "copy .a and .h files into Assets/Plugins/iOS" solution is not working on latest version of Unity. I think the only way to solve this problem is add these .a and .h files manually in XCode for now.

Comment: I see. Well I have not yet upgraded to Unity 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"copy .a and .h files into Assets/Plugins/iOS" solution is not working on latest version of Unity. I think the only way to solve this problem is add these .a and .h files manually in XCode for now.