# How to use opencv in Unity3d?

Tags: opencv, dll, unity-game-engine, integration, dynamic-library

I installed unity3D. I created a basic AR sample on it. I want to use opencv on unity3d. To do,there are some ways. I want to use opencvsharp. I install opencvsharp2.4.10 because I have installed opencv2.4.10.

I don't know next step? How I can integrate opencv with unity3d? I don't find heplful tutorial. I use 64bit and windows8.

**EDIT**

I learned that we can use c++ code(includes opencv function) in unity3d. I created dll using by visual stuio 2013. Guide link is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx). Now I try to call `substract` function in unity.

```
[DllImport ("MatFuncsDll")]
private static extern double Subtract(double a, double b);

 void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        /*Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        float dist;
        plane.Raycast (ray, out dist);
        v3OrgMouse = ray.GetPoint (dist);
        v3OrgMouse.y = 0;*/

        mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (
            mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.transform.position.x + (float)Subtract (1, 0.5),
            mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.transform.position.y,
            mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.transform.position.z);
    } 
 }
```

When I run this code I get `EntryPointNotFoundException:Substract`. I put `MathFuncDll` under `C://Program Fİles(x86)/Unity/Editor` and same directory Assets-Library under unity project.

Comment: Check this thread:
[opencv-emgucv-wrapper-integration-in-unity][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612513/opencv-emgucv-wrapper-integration-in-unity

Comment: @dArKpRiNcE I don't want to use EmguCV. EmguCV free version is only supported desktop applications, not mobile apps.

Answer (score 2):

Check this link:
[OpenCV + Unity3D integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096329/opencv-unity3d-integration)

Also there is Paid Plugin at unity Store: (it supports mobile platforms)

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/released-opencv-for-unity.277080/

Link at the store

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21088

Comment: I don't want to use extension from asset store due to not free. Thanks your help.

Comment: First Link is not for an extension. its how to use OpenCV assemblies as a plugin inside unity. it benefits from Unity's ability to include code created outside Unity in the form of a Plugin.

Comment: Do you know how to use dynamic library in unity? I want to use dynamic extension not static.

Comment: using DLL in unity can be in the form of a plugin as I mentioned earlier.
here is another link might helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923595/how-to-use-a-c-dll-in-unity3d

but regarding OpenCV Dynmic not static.. I am not quite sure because I didn't try it, and the guy in the prev link claims it must be static only...
check the official documentation from unity regarding plugins hope it can be handy to you.